# How to add sub field count to django ORM model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to send sub model count information with the main model to HTML template. I have PROJECT and Companies models:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Companies(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I need to show, projects have how many companies(company count):

```
Project name   |    company.no     
  project1     |       3     
  project2     |       5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `property` decorator to provider an arbitrary getter on your `Project` model. In your `Company` model, add a `related_name` to the `project` foreign key so you can get the reverse relationship:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='companies')
```

Then, you can add a property on your `Project` model to get the company count:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    @property
    def company_count(self):
        return self.companies.count()

    ...

# Following the sample counts you gave
print(project1.company_count)  # 3
print(project2.company_count)  # 5
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method-1 :** Using a **`GROUP BY`** statement using Django ORM

```
from django.db.models import Count

Projects.objects.values('name').annotate(count=Count('companies'))
```

This is equivalant to the SQL query, `SELECT name,Count('companies') as count from Projects`. This will return a **`QuerySet`** as,

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'project_name_1', 'count': 10}, {'name': 'project_name_2', 'count': 6}]>
```

**Method-2 :** Use [**`@property`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator (as @Kirollos Morkos mentioned )
Hence your model became

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

    @property
    def company_count(self):
        return self.companies_set.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then you'll get the comapny count in template by **`{{ project_obj.company_count}}`**

**NOTE**: The **`Method-1`** is more ***efficent and fast***, because it's being done in *database level*

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I will use not only name item. how can I user method.1 In a multi-item case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate the scenario ?

Comment: @BrainWoo you can pass in as many properties as you want to the `values` method. `Projects.objects.values('name', 'note').annotate(count=Count('companies'))` would work as well. You could also pass in no arguments to `values` in which case it will include all of your model's attributes.

Comment: @KirollosMorkos That's right, but internally it will execute as ***multiple GROUP BY*** statement (ie, `group by name group by note` like that )

Answer (score 0):

As JPG says you can use annotate. you dont need to add values queryset. see below:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Projects.objects.filter(<any filter apply to queryset>).annotate(company_count=Count('companies'))
```

you can add any field to annotation. then in your template or any code you can use this count by calling:

```
project.company_count
```

you also can add in your template

```
{{ project.companies_set.count }}
```

to get count of companies. but this method is too slow. because for each project record you have a database hit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also thought it makes DB busy.